# Is there dynamic way to access relationship in laravel using vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, foreign-keys

I want to access laravel `hasMany` relationship using vuejs without set  `index` like `[0]`..

i tried code below but, i doesn't work..

```
<pre>
<select name="shop" class="form-control"
    <option v-for="(user, index) in users" :value="user">
         {{ user.shop[index].name }}
    </option>
</select>
</pre>
```

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show all users just write  {{ user.name }}

Comment: Pls check my question again!!

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the "with" function in your controller like this:

```
$users = User::with('shop')->get();
```

That gives items the users and the user data of those users as well which allows you to access like below:

```
{{ user.shop.name }}
```